# SQL - Query optumizatin

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following two queries, and they run over a large data set. As a result they are very slow.  Can anyone help what I can do to optimize these two queries.

I am thinking there can possibly be two approaches (more?):

1. Optumize the actual queries (SELECT statements). How?
2. Optumize the tables. How? (indexes?)
3. What else?

Any help welcome and appreciated.

**Query 1**

```
SELECT a.txt_value,b.txt_value,c.txt_value,d.txt_value from tab__a a
  INNER JOIN tab__b b on a.id=b.tab__a_id
  INNER JOIN tab__c c on c.tab__b_id=b.id
  INNER JOIN tab__d d on d.tab__c_id=c.id
WHERE a.txt_value='X';
```

**Query 2**

```
SELECT a.txt_value,b.txt_value,c.txt_value,d.txt_value from tab__a a
  INNER JOIN tab__b b on a.id=b.tab__a_id
  INNER JOIN tab__c c on c.tab__b_id=b.id
  INNER JOIN tab__d d on d.tab__c_id=c.id
WHERE a.txt_value='A' and a.txt_value_2='B';
```

More info:

Here are the tables.

**Create tables:**

```
CREATE TABLE "tab__a" (
  id       BIGINT,
  txt_value VARCHAR(255),
  txt_value_2 VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE "tab__b" (
  id         BIGINT,
  tab__a_id BIGINT,
  txt_value   VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE "tab__c" (
  id         BIGINT,
  tab__b_id BIGINT,
  txt_value   VARCHAR(255)
);
CREATE TABLE "tab__d" (
  id         BIGINT,
  tab__c_id BIGINT,
  txt_value   VARCHAR(255)
);
```

**Alter tables:**

```
ALTER TABLE tab__a
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tab__a PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE tab__b
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tab__b PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE tab__c
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tab__c PRIMARY KEY (id);
ALTER TABLE tab__d
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tab__d PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE tab__b
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_1 FOREIGN KEY (tab__a_id)
REFERENCES tab__a (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE tab__c
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_2 FOREIGN KEY (tab__b_id)
REFERENCES tab__b (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;

ALTER TABLE tab__d
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_3 FOREIGN KEY (tab__c_id)
REFERENCES tab__c (id) MATCH SIMPLE
ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION;
```

More info:

PostgreSQL 9.5.19

Comment: Please read https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info for how to ask effective performance tuning questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your queries, you want the following indexes:

- `table_a(text_val, text_val_2, id)`
- `table_b(table_a_id, id, text_val)`
- `table_c(table_b_id, id, text_val)`
- `table_d(table_c_id, text_val)`

This allows both `where` clauses to filter `table_a`.  Then the remaining `join`s are handled through indexes.  As a bonus, all the columns in the query are in the indexes, so these indexes *cover* the query.

Comment: @user2569831 . . . I answered the question without realizing it was specifically for Postgres (and in fact edited the answer before submitting). In Postgres, it might be sufficient to have the indexes on only the `JOIN` columns for all but `table_a`, because Postgres loads the data pages anyway to check for locks.  Other databases have mechanisms that allow for covering indexes that do not load the data pages.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. The indexes has already improved performance 2x on the first query (one filter) and 10x on the second query (two filters).

Comment: Do you know if there's anything else I can do (other than indexes) to further improve it?

Comment: @user2569831 . . . I suspect the issue is the volume of data being returned.  That makes it hard to optimize further.